# String to Secret key conversion/Vice Versa

Tags: java, android

I am generating a Secret Key like below :
`key = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR).generateKey();`

And I want to send this key to another activity. If I use intent I think then this need to be converted into a String from Secret key. Can anyone tell me about Secret key conversion/Vice Versa...

Comment: Base64-encode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow below steps.

**From key to string**

```
`SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR").generateKey();
// Crate base64 string 
String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded());`
```

**From string to key**

```
`// decode base64 string
byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);
// rebuild key using SecretKeySpec
SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR"); `
```

**It is available from api version 8**

```
`SecretKey secretKey = null;
                try {
                    secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                byte encoded[] = secretKey.getEncoded();
                String str = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(encoded , 0);

                byte decoded[] = android.util.Base64.decode(str , 0);

                SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decoded, 0, decoded.length, "AES");'
```