# encrypt and decrypt a video in two different activities

Tags: java, android, encryption

I want to encrypt and decrypt a video in two different activities. One activity encrypts the video and other activity decrypts the video. Now the problem is, KeyGenerator generates a new key in every call. So for decrypting the video, how can I get the same key that has been used to encrypt the video?
Can I use a manual key instead of this :

`key = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR).generateKey();`
If I can then how?

Comment: Have you tried to pass the key from the first activity to the second one with `Intent` ?

Comment: yes. If I pass this SecretKey by Intent, it will be converted into a String. But I need to pass this SecretKey.

Comment: Related: [String to Secret key conversion/Vice Versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60051726/string-to-secret-key-conversion-vice-versa)

Comment: Diffie-Hellman key agreement would directly come to mind.